# No /bin-folder on asp.net core publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I made a small ASP.NET Core (2.0) project, which I thought would output files the same way the old ASP.NET 5 would - but apparently not.

In the old days I would get a `web.config`, a `bin/` with my `.dll`s, and what else I needed when I deployed to my server.

With the new project I still get a `web.config`, but all of my dependencies is laying right next to it.

I tried changing the `/p:WebPublishMethod` from `FileSystem` to `Package`, and `MSDeploy` but still no `/bin`-folder for me.

How come all my files are in the root of my publish folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Publishing an ASP.NET Core project will create an output structure that can be deployed as it is. The output format is suitable for self-hosting and to be hosted through IIS.

There is no `bin` folder simply because there does not need to be one. It’s the published output, not just intermediary build output. All the files within the publish directory are required to host your application.

Comment: Dos this still apply in 2019, I'm ok with the output, but people doing deployment find this new structure very different than the former asp.net

Comment: @CryingFreeman Yes, publishing an ASP.NET Core project will give you a folder with everything you need to host it. You need to point IIS to that folder. And yeah, it is very different to classic ASP.NET since it works very differently. See also the docs on [hosting with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just switching a website over to VS2019 from VS2017, and having the same issue.  I discovered that VS2019 has totally new publish settings, and these don't seem to be initialised properly when coming over from VS2017.  Instead of precompiling, the publish happens with all the .aspx.cs files not compiled.

To fix it, follow these steps...

- Under Build, Publish Web App, once you have setup the folder profile to publish to, in the summary section, there is a Configuration setting.  Click on the Pencil icon on the "Configuration Line".
- This will show Publish Settings
- Open up the File Publish Options
- Turn on "Precompile during publishing"
- Save the settings and click on "Publish"

Now it's like it was in VS2017, with a bin directory of dll files.

Comment: In my case there is no such settings. I am using VS2019.
File Publish options has only one option - Delete all existing files prior to publish